# Django annotate on several fields related to same model

Tags: python, django

I have two models:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    ...

class Transaction(models.Model):
    ....
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account)
    source_account = models.ForeignKey(Account, null=True)
```

I need to display the number of transactions for each of a user's accounts. Django's `annotate` seemed like the proper tool for this task. I did:

```
queryset = models.Account.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
queryset.annotate(transactions_count=Count('transaction'))
```

This gives the correct number for transactions with `account` field set to the predicate account but leaves out transactions where `source_account` is set to the predicate account.

Using the Django shell I am able to do something like:

```
accounts_count = user_transactions.filter(Q(account=account)|Q(source_account=account)).count()
```

This gives the correct answer. Is there something I am doing wrong? Can someone point me in the correct direction. Any assistance is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would set `related_name` to your `ForeignKey` fields. Then it's a bit easier to work with them. So for example in your models let's set:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    ...
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, related_name='transactions')
    source_account = models.ForeignKey(Account, null=True, related_name='source_transactions')
```

then can do something like:

```
 queryset = models.Account.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).annotate(transactions_count=(Count('transactions')+Count('source_transactions'))
```

it would work without the naming too, it's just more readable and easier. The main point is adding the two `Count` as one field in `annotate`.

The best approach for these types of problems is to imagine them in raw SQL and then try to mimic it in Django ORM. 
(in raw sql you would also simply just add two columns like `SELECT (a.col + a.col2) AS count`

Comment: I had to add `distinct=True` to the `Count` calls. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your transaction has to ForgeinKeys to Account. I would suggest trying something like this

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    ....
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, related_name="transaction_account")
    source_account = models.ForeignKey(Account, null=True, related_name="transaction_source_account")
```

Then in your query:

```
queryset.annotate(transactions_count=((Count('transaction_account') +  Count('transaction_source_account'))
```